# Bash - node: command not found when being run in a shell script

Tags: windows, windows-10, bash, node.js

When trying to run a node command from a .sh script I get the error `node: command not found`, however I can see that node is installed, running `node -v` shows me my current version, what could be the cause of this?

Looking around others with similar issues they all were related to node not being in PATH, however I can see that it is the first value in my variable:

[image]

What else would I need to check to be able to run this command?

Comment: “When trying to run a node command from a .sh…” It probably is not getting the full path in the Bash script. Confirm by putting `echo $PATH;` in the shell script about where the node command is. If that is the case, the best thing to do is set the full path for node in the script.

Comment: Any nodejs installed under `\Program Files` is likely a native-windows port meaning the executable is actually `node.exe`. Windows "command prompt" (CMD) or PowerShell when given the command `node` automatically adds the `.exe`, but ports of Unix shells often don't because this 'feature' doesn't exist on Unix.

Comment: I've specifically added `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe` to the path, can see it when I `echo $PATH`, yet still get an error that node can't be found.